# How to use enum as datasource in comboboxedit

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone explain me how can I use data stored in enum as values in comboboxedit? What I'm trying to do is to bind this data with user control with is used to edit gridview records. What is the code to do so ?

Comment: Might want to add the appropriate tags; given "comboboxedit" and "gridview" is this is webforms?

Comment: comboboxedit - servicecomboboxedit, enum - enService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use enum in comboboxedit you can try to use this code:

ComboBoxEdit1.Properties.DataSource = GetType(EnumName).GetEnumValues()

Just replace name of comboboxedit with your and enum name with your.